# Crontab + Journalctl: extra messages

Tags: logging, cron, systemd, journal

Disclaimer: the following describes things done for learning purposes in CentOS 7.

I want to redirect the output of a crontab job to `journalctl`.
When I have the following record, it just sends a mail to root user.

```
# crontab -l
* * * * * echo "Hello World"
```

I've read about `systemd-cat` which can execute a process, piping it's output to the journal.
So I made it like this:

```
# crontab -l 
* * * * * systemd-cat -t "cron-bot" echo "Hello World"
```

But now I receive two log messages every minute:

```
{
  "_TRANSPORT" : "syslog",
  "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "CROND",
  "MESSAGE" : "(root) CMD (systemd-cat -t \"cron-bot\" echo \"Hello World\")",
  "_CMDLINE" : "systemd-cat -t cron-bot echo Hello World",
}
{
  "_TRANSPORT" : "stdout",
  "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "cron-bot",
  "MESSAGE" : "Hello World",
  "_COMM" : "echo",
}
```

or, in short format:

```
Sep 06 08:58:01 hostname CROND[13417]: (root) CMD (systemd-cat -t "cron-bot" echo "Hello World")
Sep 06 08:58:01 hostname cron-bot[13417]: Hello World
```

Can someone explain this behavior to me? I'd like to receive only the job ouput (`cron-bot[13417]: Hello World`)
and do not receive the command itself (`CROND[13417]: ...`) but mostly I'm asking this to learn more about the topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cron` logs each command it runs to syslog, and on your system the syslog ends up in the journal as well. As far as I’m aware, `cron` doesn’t have an option to disable that, but you can hide those messages by selecting only those journal messages received via stdout:

```
journalctl -u cron _TRANSPORT=stdout
```

(`-u cron` might be `-u crond` or something like that on CentOS, I’m not sure.)

Comment: Pro tip.. if you are not exactly sure of the name of the `-u` / `--unit` you can use globs.. `journalctl -u "cron*"` and it will match `cron`, `crond` or whatver `cronthingy` it might be called on your system.

Answer (score 3):

The log entry for `"SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "CROND"` is showing you that cron is executing a command and what command that is.

The log entry for `"SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "cron-bot"` is showing your your script output.

Since you used the tagging ability of `journalctl` with including `-t "cron-bot"` you can pull your desired output by filtering what you are pulling from `journalctl`. That `-t` is what sets the `SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER`. (I think you already knew that )

Something like this is what I've used many times to get specific logs out of the journal:

```
journalctl -fet "cron-bot"
```

That should display just your output and not the cron/crond output of the journal.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/journalctl.1.html

```
-f, --follow
  Show only the most recent journal entries, and continuously
  print new entries as they are appended to the journal.

-e, --pager-end
  Immediately jump to the end of the journal inside the implied
  pager tool. This implies -n1000 to guarantee that the pager
  will not buffer logs of unbounded size. This may be
  overridden with an explicit -n with some other numeric value,
  while -nall will disable this cap. Note that this option is
  only supported for the less(1) pager.

-t, --identifier=SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER
  Show messages for the specified syslog identifier
  SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER.
  This parameter can be specified multiple times.
```